# keycloak integration with mssql

Tags: keycloak

i have had a problem when run that config

```
E:\keycloak\keycloak server\keycloak-17.0.0> bin/kc.bat start --db-url-host=host of db --db-username=username --db-password=pass --hostname=localhost --db-schema=keycloak --db-url=sqlserver://192.168.129.129/keycloak
```

---

```
2023-02-21 00:36:03,531 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': No suitable driver found for sqlserver://myhost/keycloak 2023-02-21 00:36:03,532 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: keycloak-default) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for sqlserver://myhost/keycloak
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:191)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:352)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:216)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:513)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:494)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Using this [yml](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/main/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-mssql.yml) with `docker compose`